# Submit an universal app as iPhone onlly

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm developing an universal app and i'm not finished with the iPad version. How can I submit just the iphone version without creating a new project or deleting iPad viewcontroller classes/codes which is in the universal app project. Will Apple approve such submission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your project and click on the summary tab. Below the bundle identifier and the version number there is a devices drop down change this from universal to iPhone.

[image]